# Spring Boot 2.1.0 @Controller is not working?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

`Spring Boot 2.1.0 @Controller` for Web MVC is not working but when I write `services(Rest) with @RestController` then it works.

The error what i getting is `White Label Error 404`.

Edit: I was missing dot in properties files and that was the reason I was not able to call view. Now I updated my code and everything is working fine. Thanks

Comment: No code, no error, no stack trace, no log, no scenario. We can't help.

Answer (score 0):

@RestController != @Controller

@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody